# Why do I keep getting this error, Module not found: Error: can't resolve..., in Vuex when using store.js and importing store to my main.js file?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using Vuex and using store.js for the first time.  In my main.js file I am using

```js
import { store } from './store/store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and everytime I run this I keep getting this error.

```
ERROR in ./src/store/store.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.vue' in '/Users/briansantos/code/Vuex/src/store'
 @ ./src/store/store.js 1:0-23
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi main

ERROR in ./src/store/store.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '.vuex' in '/Users/briansantos/code/Vuex/src/store'
 @ ./src/store/store.js 2:0-25
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi main
```

I have tried scouring the internet and have found several peopole saying that this is a dependency issue and I have checked for updates and with no luck have found an answer. Below is my store.js file in my store folder.

```js
import Vue from '.vue';
import Vuex from '.vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        counter: 0
    }
})
```

If anyone could help me understand what is happening and how to correct this.  Here is the repo all you have to do is clone and npm install.

https://github.com/brianmsantos/Vuex

Comment: Remove the dots ~ `import Vue from 'vue'; import Vuex from 'vuex';`. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html#npm

Comment: To help you understand, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import. The _"module-name"_ part should match the module in your `node_modules` directory. You have modules named "vue" and "vuex", **not** ".vue" and ".vuex"

Comment: Thanks Phil, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the imports of Vue packages. You have to remove the dot prefix from them, like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
```

Those packages come from `node_modules`, thus don't need to be prefixed by `.`